# Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 is showing problems

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, vlc

I switched from Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 using "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade". The Home folder icon on my desktop in 20.04, when I open it, it starts opening VLC instead, that too, the VLC opened starts flickering and then it appears, "VLC is not responding".
I uninstalled VLC via "sudo apt -get autoremove --purge vlc". After that, Home folder icon worked fine, opened Home in files, but I reinstalled VLC and it shows the same error.

Is it not safe to upgrade like this?
If not, then what should I do now?

Also, my Software Updater is showing, "Not all updates have been installed".

Comment: "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" does not a release upgrade do. But regadless of what you really did. it seems to have some problems and very likely inherited. Many user think that an online release upgrade fixes problems but that's seldom the case, it often makes them worse. The solution for all this problem though is a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is incomplete, but it seems like you have two possibilities:

1. You have discovered an issue with the VLC package.

   Answer: Test to see if you can reproduce using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If so, file a bug report. If not, move on to #2.
2. Your system is broken due to a botched unsupported dist-upgrade.

   Answer: Backup and clean-install. Next time, use `do-release-upgrade`, which is the tested and supported method.